# Deprecated Java EE in JDK 9 and later versions

Tags: java, java-9

I want to know why JDK 9 no longer has the Java EE version. I was reading that since the JDK 9 version no longer has Java EE, then Java EE's own functions would appear as deprecated.  Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Migrate to [Jakarta EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_EE)

Answer (score 5):

> I want to know why JDK 9 no longer has the JAVA EE version.

Java EE / J2EE was never part of Java SE releases (JDK / JRE).  While the version numbering was similar, this was largely a "marketing thing".  Certainly the SE and EE release cycles were not the same.

Anyway, Oracle has passed control of Java EE over to the Eclipse Foundation; see [Jakarta EE 8: The new era of Java EE explained](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/09/12/jakarta-ee-8-the-new-era-of-java-ee-explained/)

---

> I was reading that java ee's own functions would appear as deprecated.

If someone actually wrote that Java EE is dead or "deprecated", they are incorrect.  (Or at least, they are out of date.)

1. Java EE has now become Jakarta EE, and Jakarta EE has a clear future (see link above)
2. Even if it didn't have a clear future, that wouldn't amount to deprecation.

---

> Do you know how to solve this problem?

I don't think there is a problem to solve.

The reality is that Oracle had lost interest in Java EE<sup>1</sup>, and progress  under Oracle's stewardship had ground to a virtual halt.  Jakarta EE is effectively a reboot.

While predicting the future is difficult, there are reasons to believe that both Java/Jakata EE vendors and Java EE/Jakata users will be better of with the new model.  The first test will be the upcoming Jakarta EE 9 release which is scheduled for August / September 2020.  (Check the [Jakarta EE 9 home page](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-platform/jakartaee9/JakartaEE9) for the latest news on the schedule.)

This Eclipse newsletter from last year gives a taster of what should be in the release:

- [Jakarta EE 9 - 2019 Outlook](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2019/february/Jakarta_EE_9.php)

---

<sup>1 - Java EE / Jakarta EE is essentially a set of specifications.  Writing and maintaining high quality specifications is expensive.  Since Oracle didn't have any significant (money making) Java EE products, Oracle management decided that it was not worth continuing to invest in that aspect of Java.  Passing control to an other organization was the responsible thing to do.  The renaming was necessary for legal reasons; e.g. protecting Oracle's Java trademark.</sup>